# Handling 413 (Request Entity Too Large) error with try/catch

Tags: reactjs, redux, try-catch, http-status-code-413

I am trying to figure out how to handle 413 error when uploading files, `to show the user that the file they are trying to upload is too large`. I am uploading the files from a component in **React** using **React-dropzone**, then pass it to **sagas**, then a function in sagas will loop through the file and send each files to **Rails** - upload the files using **Carrierwave** then **rails** will send back some data if the upload success.

**MyUploadComponent.jsx**

```
this.state = {
    files: [{file1}, {file2}, {file3}]
}

uploadFiles = () => {
    this.props.saveFiles(this.state.files)
}
```

**sagas.js**

```
function* saveFiles(action){
    let err = false  
    let completed;

    const results = yield Promise.all(action.files.map(function(file){

        return saveFile(file)

    })).then(data => {

        completed = data

    })

    yield put({
        type: actionTypes.FILE_UPLOADED,
        index: completed
    })

}

function saveFile(file, cid, index){
    try{
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("file", file)

        let result = fetch(URL,
        {
            method: "POST",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            body: formData
        }).then(response => response.json()).then(function(data){
            return data
        })

        return result
    } catch(ex) { console.log(ex) }

}
```

### When I am having 413 error, I also receive this additional message

[error 413 File too large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRdL8.png)

Comment: how did you resolve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just check reponse.status for deciding how to handle the response:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#response_objects